# 301 redirect in nginx with or without arguments

Tags: nginx

I want to redirect to a subdomain every call to mydomain.com/blog2, so far I have this:

```
location ^~ /blog2/$ {
    return 301 https://blog.mydomain.com$request_uri$is_args$args;
}
```

This works only for mydomain.com/blog2/, /blog2 with no trailing slash or /blog2/somethingelse breaks. /blog2/somethingelse/ goes to blog.mydomain.com without the somethingelse part.

How can I achieve:

```
mydomain.com/blog2                    --> blog.mydomain.com
mydomain.com/blog2/                   --> blog.mydomain.com
mydomain.com/blog2/something          --> blog.mydomain.com/something
mydomain.com/blog2/something/         --> blog.mydomain.com/something
mydomain.com/blog2/something?foo=bar  --> blog.mydomain.com/something?foo=bar
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to remove the `/blog2/` part of the URL, you cannot use `$request_uri` as it contains the original URI in full. You will need to capture the parts of the URI you need with a regular expression as part of a `location` or `rewrite` statement.

Using a regular expression `location` statement:

```
location ~ ^/blog2(?:/(.*))?$ {
    return 301 https://blog.mydomain.com/$1$is_args$args;
}
```

Which is probably the same as:

```
rewrite ^/blog2(?:/(.*))?$ https://blog.mydomain.com/$1 permanent;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for more.